# Audible noise coming from Inductor when using LT3760 driver circuit

Tags: power, capacitor, inductor, led-driver

[image]I have an audible noise from inductor when I use LT3760. When PWM is 20kHz, the noise is at 10kHz. Whenever I switch PWM, the noise is at half of PWM. Where does it come from ?

Comment: Ok, I hate to surprise you, but: the noise comes *from the PWM*.

Comment: But not on every PCBA. So, what will be the explanation ?

Comment: Show your circuit and give link to the inductor data sheet.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/wurth-electronics-inc/7447798221/732-2419-1-ND/2268711

Comment: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3760fc.pdf

Comment: **Edit** your question and add the schematic and datasheets. Without that, the best answer you can get is my first comment.

Comment: magnetic fields have the tendency of wanting to move things around

Comment: Do you really have no output capacitor in LED+ line?

Comment: Have you tried adding a loading resistor? or increasing current draw?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the standard circuit provided by LT: -

[image]

I note that your circuit does not have 5x 2.2 uF capacitors on the output of your boost regulator (after the schottky diode, D43). I've drawn a red circle around them.

This could easily be a significant factor in causing your problem. It's there to smooth the current through the inductor when the LEDs are being switched with PWM. Try it out.

If they are present and you haven't shown it on the diagram then you are naughty.

Answer (score 1):

the fact that a 20kHz PWM registers with a 10kHz tone might be

- due to your measurement device being somewhat sensitive to 20kHz, but interpreting it as 10 kHz (for example, due to aliasing, or intermodulation)
- by the fact that a PWM has a mean spectral shape with a lot of side lobes that spectrally might contain 10 kHz mathematically – if you have a 20 kHz PWM set at 25% duty cycle, I think I can see a spectral product at 10kHz (too lazy to do the Fourier transform of the signal in my head).
- the fact that some things just happen every other cycle
- mechanical nonlinearities

In any case, I don't really know what to tell you. As said in the comments, coils tend to squee a bit.

Comment: Thank you. And don't know how to get rid of this 10kHz tone.

Comment: Short answer: bad luck. Try different inductors, boards, glue, and acoustic dampening.

Comment: Uhm, no, a periodic signal at 20 kHz has no 10 kHz component, regardless of duty cycle. If there is truly a 10 kHz component, it must be that something just happen (more at) every other cycle.

Comment: @fgrieu you're absolutely right; there might be slower periodic changes that might themselves be at 10 kHz or have harmonics at 10kHz, but if you consider an arbitrary sub-50% duty-cycle PWM as product of two slightly time-shifted square waves (rel. shift half-period: 0% duty cycle, rel. shift 0: 50% duty cycle), then yeah, it's just convolution of the square waves cosine series with itself and a factor of $e^{j2\pi\Delta t f}$ in freq. domain.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the component generating the noise indeed is the inductor; that happens by the phenomenon known as [magnetostriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction). Firmly pressing the inductor (with a properly isolated finger) might damp the noise, and allow to confirm that indeed the inductor is the source.

Now, if the PWM is at 20kHz and there is a 10kHz component to the noise, it means that the PWM conducts significantly longer at odd cycles than it does at even cycles; that's might be visible at TP56. BUT the PWM is not supposed to be operating at 20kHz in the first place. RT of 60.4k is supposed to give about 700kHz, and 20kHz is off-chart!

[image: Frequency versus RT]

Most likely, there is some serious instability in the control loop. As rightly pointed in [that other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/269657/22496), the capacitors at the output of the rectifier are missing, and that likely contributes. I fear it also means that the circuit radiates much more EMI than it should.

Comment: The PWM in question is not the main switching frequency of the device but the PWM brightness control frequency.

Comment: Oooooh! OOOOOH!